# Identifying infinitives

Tags: modal-verbs, infinitives, to-infinitive

In "I have to go there" is 'go' an infinitive or the main verb? I have read somewhere that infinitives can be used after 'have to' and the above mentioned sentence was given as an example. If that's correct then how about "I must go there"? I am pretty sure in this case 'go' is the main verb.

Comment: Yes, after both 'have to' and 'must' we use the bare infinitive, that is, without 'to'.

Comment: Okay. Are 'have to' and 'must' regarded as principal verbs in these two sentences then?

Comment: @JMB It's not a bare infinitive but a _to_-infinitival following stative "have".

Comment: @BillJ What about the second sentence?? Which is the principal verb?

Comment: The verb is "have", not "have to". You can take "have" as the principal verb. It has the subordinate _to_ infinitival clause "to go there" as its complement.

Comment: In your second sentence, you can take "must" as the principal verb. It has the subordinate infinitival clause "to go there" as its complement.

Comment: Note that "go" is a non-finite verb in your examples, whereas "have" and "must" are finite.

Comment: @BillJ What confused me is 'must' being used as a principal verb. I thought modal verbs were exclusively auxiliaries.

Comment: Yes, the modals are auxiliaries, and the auxiliaries are finite verbs. For example A says to B, "Must you go so soon?", B then replies "Yes, I must". "Have" is slightly different, most speakers treat it as a lexical verb, others as an auxiliary.

Comment: I get your point. But I am more concerned about the terminology here. Finite verbs are classified into principal and auxiliary verbs, right? And auxiliaries are sometimes used as principals; e.g. in "He is reading"  'is' is an auxiliary verb but in "He is a man"  'is' is said to be acting as a principal verb(please correct me if i am wrong) . Now if someone were to ask me which kind of verb 'must' is in "he must go", should my answer be 'auxiliary' or should it be 'principal'? Or does it not matter at all?

Answer (score 1):

> *I have* [*to go there*].
>
> *I must* [*go there*].

In these examples, the bracketed elements are subordinate infinitival clauses functioning as catenative complement of "have" and "must".

The sentences as a whole are called the matrix clauses, within which the infinitival clauses are subordinate.

Thus, you could if you wished call "have" and "must" the principal or main verbs, since they are the verbs of the upper (matrix) clauses. But those are just general, not grammatical, terms. Grammarians would call "must" and "have" the matrix verbs, and "go" the subordinate verb.

Note that the subordinate (dependent) clauses can be dropped, for example

A: "Must you go so soon?"

B: "Yes, I must"

Answer (score 0):

> I like to go there.
> I want to go there.
> I need to go there.
> I have to go there.

Under a traditional analysis, "like", "want", "need" and "have" are all main verbs in these examples.   The verb "to go" is a full infinitive.   The infinitive phrase "to go there" is the direct object of the main verb.

> I can go there.
> I will go there.
> I should go there.
> I must go there.

Here, "can", "will", "should" and "must" are all auxiliaries.  The "go", which is a bare infinitive, is called the main verb.

The reason they are called main verbs has to do with the way that conjugation was traditionally taught:

> I **have** to go there.
> I **had** to go there.
> I **will have** to go there.
> I **might have had** to go there.
> I **could have been having** to go there.

> I **go** there.
> I **went** there.
> I **will go** there.
> I **must go** there.
> I **will be going** there.
> I **could have been going** there.

All of these conjugated verb start with a finite verb form and, if they continue, only contain participles and bare infinitives thereafter.   Once you reach something else, such as the "to" of a full infinitive, you've gone past the end of the conjugated verb.

The verb *have* is a tricky little thing.   Sometimes it's an auxiliary to some main verb.   Sometimes it's a main verb with its own auxiliaries.   In "could have been having", it appears once in each role.

It's also tricky in that, instead of having its usual *possessive* sense, it carries *obligatory* semantics when it is followed by a full infinitive.